# need guidance on new streamlined topology for design sharepoint 2013 Farm for internet faced sites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, architecture, topology

For internet based share point web application it has below statistics

```
Total Number of Search Queries : 1928

Total Number of Daily Unique Visitors: 800

No of page views per daily : 3334
```

How i design the topology and how i use new stream lined topology?

My requirements is
- i want to allocate dedicated search server 
  -- **which search component should i run in this server?**

- i want to allocate dedicated application server Performance point and excel services ( we have heavy use off SSAS data sources to build BI dashboards)
- I want to add two Web Servers for web application
  -- **in this which services should i run 
  can i run the request management and distributed cache services 
  and share point foundation web application service in these two servers?**

-- **for other Search services query processing should i run in WFE server?**

**which services should i run front end servers ?
and in batch processing servers?**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the specifications, I would say you are building a small farm. So below is the configuration that can be suggested

Two WFE' - you can run the request management (this services is really not needed and even you can disable it - please plan to use a load balanced environment such as F5 if you can afford) , Central Admin, distributed cache, app frabic services and share point foundation web application service will be in these two servers.

Two App servers/batch servers:

One dedicated for all search related components
One dedicated for BI specific requirements and others - PPS, user profile, visio, workflow,STS, Excel, BCS and so on.

One DB environment with fail-over configuration.

Overall, you can even consider just a single WFE since your page views is around 800. but it is advisable to have another just for a failover purpose and based on Severity.

Comment: Hi thanks, for central administration service and sharepoint foundatinweb application service should be allow  in same server for performance ? and should i run distributed cache service also in WFE servers compulsory ?

Comment: we have already planned F5 for load balance so is request management service also needed to run in WFE servers?